# Comprobar una palabra en java

Tags: java, base-de-datos

estoy haciendo un programa que de tres columnas en una base de datos de Access (una con la palabra en inglés, otra con la palabra en castellano y otra con la definición) dándome la palabra en inglés, tengo que poner la traducción.

El problema viene en que algunas palabras tienen varias traducciones y en la celda de la segunda columna hay varias palabras, me gustaría que al poner una de esas palabras me diera ya por buena la respuesta. Ahora mismo etoy usando simplemente un equals:

```
if (resultSet.getString(2).equals(res)) {
   System.out.println("Well done!");
}
```

He pensado en poner un indexOf como:

```
if (resultSet.getString(2).indexOf(res) != -1)
```

Pero tengo el problema de, por ejemplo, en *lumberjack* daria por buena *leña* cuando solo seria *leñador*.

¿Que debería de hacer para que funcionara bien?

EDIT: el código es este

```
public class DataConn {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // variables
        Connection connection = null;
        Statement statement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        int score = 0;
        Scanner ans = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean finished = false;
        String res;

        // Step 1: Loading or registering Oracle JDBC driver class
        try {
            Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfex) {
            System.out.println("Problem in loading or registering MS Access JDBC driver");
            cnfex.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Step 2: Opening database connection
        try {
            String msAccessDBName = "C:\\Users\\Pau\\Documents\\vocabulary.accdb";
            String dbURL = "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + msAccessDBName;

            // Step 2.A: Create and get connection using DriverManager class
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL);

            // Step 2.B: Creating JDBC Statement
            statement = connection.createStatement();

            // Step 2.C: Executing SQL & retrieve data into ResultSet
            resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM vocabulary ORDER BY RAND()");
            System.out.println(ConsoleColors.BLUE_BOLD + "Translate the next words" + ConsoleColors.RESET);
            while(resultSet.next() && !finished) {
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString(1) + " " + ConsoleColors.YELLOW +
                        resultSet.getString(4) + ConsoleColors.RESET);
                res = ans.nextLine();
                if (res.equals("exit")) {
                    finished = true;
                }
                else {
                    if (resultSet.getString(2).indexOf(res) != -1) {
                        System.out.println("Well done!");
                        score++;
                    } else {
                        System.out.println(ConsoleColors.RED + "Wrong answer!" + ConsoleColors.RESET);
                        System.out.println(ConsoleColors.YELLOW + "The correct translation is: " +
                                resultSet.getString(2) + ConsoleColors.RESET);
                        if(score > 0)
                            score--;
                    }
                    System.out.println("Definition: " + resultSet.getString(3));
                    System.out.println(" ");
                    resultSet.next();
                }
            }
            System.out.println(ConsoleColors.CYAN + "Final score = " + score);

            // processing returned data and printing into console
        }
        catch(SQLException sqlex){
            sqlex.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally {
            // Step 3: Closing database connection
            try {
                if(null != connection) {
                    // cleanup resources, once after processing
                    resultSet.close();
                    statement.close();

                    // and then finally close connection
                    connection.close();
                }
            }
            catch (SQLException sqlex) {
                sqlex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola buenos días. Te recomendaría poner el código completo de tu programa. Ya que estaría bien saber como recuperas los datos y como los procesas. Por lo que dices en el enunciado, estas diciendo que la aplicación te da una palabra en ingles en un campo, tu pones la traducción en otro campo y la aplicación te indica si es correcta o no ¿verdad? ademas entiendo de que de una palabra en ingles, hay varias traducciones que contarían como correctas.

Comment: exacto, ya he puesto el código entero

Comment: En que momento estas comparando lo que ingreso el usuario con lo que tenes en la base de datos?

Comment: Con el if (resultSet.getString(2).indexOf(res) != -1) compruebo si la palabra esta en la celda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo tomaría la segunda columna y usaría el StringTokenizer lo recorro y comparo las palabras para ver si es correcto, en cuanto vea que son iguales la da por buena

o pueden usar el contains pero yo usaría un UpperCase o lowerCase para no tener problemas con que sean diferentes solo por mayúsculas o  minúsculas.

Comment: Bienvenido y gracias por tus contribuciones Eduardo, en cuanto a que aún no tienes [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation),debes obtenerla realizando aportaciones al sitio, en este caso respondiendo de acuerdo a [answer], ediciones a las publicaciones, etc revisa por favor  [¿Como obtener reputación?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).  Te invitamos a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio

Answer (score 0):

Ya veo cual es el problema de tu código.

```
res = ans.nextLine();
/*
...
*/
if (resultSet.getString(2).indexOf(res) != -1) {
 //Codigo
}
```

La variable `res` contiene la respuesta del usuario y `resultSet.getString(2)` es la respuesta esperada.

No tiene ningun sentido que uses el `indexOf(...) != -1` para comparar si dos cadenas son iguales. Por eso, en tu ejemplo da buena la palabra leña cuando buscas leñador; por que la palabra leñador, contiene dentro leña.

Sustituye el `indexOf(...)` por `equals(...)` o `equalsIgnoreCase(...)` para no preocuparnos por mayúsculas.