# Quisiera sacar información de un try-catch para poder ponerselo a un JTextField con .setText

Tags: java, ms-access, jdbc

Quisiera saber como sacar los datos de la variable cod, para poder mostrarla fuera del try-catch

```
if("hola".equals(cod)){
                 System.out.println(cod);
             }
```

como vemos en la parte de arriba ese es el fragmento de codigo que pregunto

```
        try{
            String cod2;
        
        String usuario = "2";
        ruta = "SELECT cedula,nombre FROM usuarios WHERE cedula = '"+usuario+"' ";
        
        prestado = con.prepareStatement(ruta);
        
        resultado1 = prestado.executeQuery();
            
        
         while (resultado1.next()){
             String cod = resultado1.getString("cedula");
              cod2 = resultado1.getString("nombre");
             if("hola".equals(cod)){
                 System.out.println(cod);
             }

         }
        }catch(SQLException r){
            System.out.println(r);
```

he intentado poner el cod fuera del metodo pero me devuelve valor: null cuando lo llamo desde afuera con el System.out.println(cod);

Comment: ¿Ya probaste accediendo por índice en vez de nombre de columna como en https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/286835/comprobar-una-palabra-en-java ?

Comment: Entiendo bien? Quieres usar la variable cod fuera del try catch? Y que pasa con cod2? Podrías mostrar el código completo y donde y qué quieres hacer con cod?

Comment: el "cod" solo lo utilizo en esa parte del codigo, que lo utilizo de referencia para buscar el nombre de la persona

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplemente define afuera del método la variable `cod`:

```
 private String cod = "";
```

entonces dentro de tu código solo asignas el valor y este valor sera leído en toda la clase, de esta forma podrías asignarlo a tu `JTextField`:

```
        try{
            String cod2;
        
        String usuario = "2";
        ruta = "SELECT cedula,nombre FROM usuarios WHERE cedula = '"+usuario+"' ";
        
        prestado = con.prepareStatement(ruta);
        
        resultado1 = prestado.executeQuery();
            
        
         while (resultado1.next()){

             //String cod = resultado1.getString("cedula");

              cod = resultado1.getString("cedula");
              cod2 = resultado1.getString("nombre");
             if("hola".equals(cod)){
                 System.out.println(cod);
             }

         }
        }catch(SQLException r){
            System.out.println(r);
```

Comment: muchas gracias bro